# Why a unix-socket file remains after its creator exits? Can I reuse it?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix

I work with unix sockets for the first time, and I stumbled upon a problem with unix socket file not getting automatically removed. It seems, after I create a socket, I can't just exit a program, instead I should remove the socket file as well.

But why the socket file doesn't get destroyed after the program that created it quits? It looks like there should be a way to connect somehow an application to this remaining file, or why is it still there?

Below is a code to illustrate *(it creates a unix socket  and then just exits)*:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

int CreateSocket(const char* filename) {
    if (strlen(filename) > sizeof(sockaddr_un::sun_path)) {
        puts("Too long filename!");
        return -1;
    }
    int fdSock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(fdSock == -1){
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    sockaddr_un server;
    server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server.sun_path, filename);
    if(bind(fdSock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(sockaddr_un)) == -1){
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eww... `if(0 > fdSock)` ... Yoda expressions are hideous, don't use them.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I am disagree. I found this very useful when I write a comparison with some very long expression. I.e. here `if(0 > bind(fdSock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(sockaddr_un)))` no need to seek somewhere in the end with what the comparison done.

Comment: Don't seek, hide. `if (unix_bind(fdSock, &server) < 0)`...

Comment: Just keep writing more server code, instead of exiting. What's the problem?

Comment: @EJP just a curiosity. That was just little test application(in order to see how the unix sockets works), and I become really curious why this file remains. Here should be a reasons.

Comment: So what *is* your question? There's one in your title and another implied by your text and comments.

Comment: @EJP sorry if I vaguely told... Well, I doesn't understand why the unix-socket file remains after the old server exits. It looks like I can create a new server, and use an old socket file. And that is the question: how to do it?(of course if it is not possible, and the file remains for some other reasons, this answer okay too, I just want to know it).

Comment: Ok, so if that's your question, fix your title.

Comment: 2021, still no good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Short quote from the awesome book **"The Sockets Networking API: UNIX® Network Programming Volume 1, Third Edition"** by *W. Richard Stevens; Bill Fenner; Andrew M. Rudoff*.

**Chapter 15**. Example: bind of Unix Domain Socket.

> *Remove pathname first.* The pathname that we bind to the socket is the command-line argument. But the bind will fail if the pathname already exists in the filesystem. Therefore, we call unlink to delete the pathname, in case it already exists. If it does not exist, unlink returns an error, which we ignore.

Actually, you can use the path to detect the server exists. When server terminating it have to remove a file to let the client to understand there is no server that can read incoming connections. For example **Docker** works this way: if the daemon not spawned there is no `docker.sock` file in your system.

Comment: I don't think you can use it to check that the server exists, because if a server has crashed, or simply for whatever reason couldn't remove the file, the file would still be there while the server is not. Anyway, what I originally wondered here, is the reasoning why the file is not removed by system. As it is, since nobody addressed this point, it looks like simply a mistake in either unix sockets API or its implementation *(depending on whether it's mandated by API or not)*

Answer (score 3):

Unix domain sockets operate on files so you can use all the file permission features on them etc.
However if you do not care for these you actually want to use `abstract unix domain sockets`, by setting `sun_path[0]` to `'\0'`:

> abstract: an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a
> pathname socket) by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte
> ('\0').  The socket's address in this namespace is given by
> the additional bytes in sun_path that are covered by the
> specified length of the address structure.  (Null bytes in the
> name have no special significance.)  The name has no
> connection with filesystem pathnames.  When the address of an
> abstract socket is returned, the returned addrlen is greater
> than sizeof(sa_family_t) (i.e., greater than 2), and the name
> of the socket is contained in the first (addrlen -
> sizeof(sa_family_t)) bytes of sun_path.

As claimed, they do not respect the file permission operations:

> Socket permissions have no meaning for abstract sockets: the
> process umask(2) has no effect when binding an abstract socket,
> and changing the ownership and permissions of the object (via
> fchown(2) and fchmod(2)) has no effect on the accessibility of
> the socket.

When you process exists you can safely reuse the identifier used in `bind`:

> Abstract sockets automatically disappear when all open references
> to the socket are closed.

However mind you that this is a non-portable linux extension:

> The abstract socket namespace is a nonportable Linux extension.

[Source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)

Comment: While it doesn't clarify why unix socket files are not automatically deleted, but ⁺¹ for a good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot fully understand your questions. I think you do not understand the `socket()` mechanism. 
I will explain. Socket here is similar to pointer or file descriptor. 
There are two different programs: the server and the client. They are not dependent. Server opens a socket and waits for a connection. Client opens its OWN socket, connects to a remote address. Server handles the connection. Data exchange between these two programs occurs, then (if necessary) connections are terminated. 
Here are examples of simplest client and server programs for TCP/IP, they show how the `socket()` mechanism works.

Server code:

```
void * server (void)
{
    int listenfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    socklen_t lenkeepalive;
    struct net_pack recvline;
    int i,n;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(PORT);

    bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    int keepalive =1;
    lenkeepalive = sizeof(keepalive);
    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &keepalive, lenkeepalive) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: setsockopt()");
        shutdown(listenfd,SHUT_RDWR);
        close(listenfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_create (NULL, NULL, (void *)server_send, NULL);

    for(;;)
    {

        if(connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA *) NULL, NULL)>0){
            bzero(&recvline, sizeof(recvline));
            //try get msg from connected client
            while ( (recv(connfd, &recvline, MAXLINE, 0)) > 0)
            {
                printf("server: recvline.msg - %s\n",recvline.msg);
                bzero(&recvline, sizeof(recvline));
                /*
                    ...
                */
                // send answ

                encode(&recvline,"hello2",H); //make a msg

                if(send(connfd, &recvline, (strlen(recvline.msg)+4), MSG_NOSIGNAL); < 0)
                {
                    printf("server_send: send error %d (%s)\n",errno, strerror(errno));
                }

                //discard client connection
                shutdown(connfd,SHUT_RDWR);
                close(connfd);
            }

        }

    }

    // some error occurs    
    perror("server: accept()");
    shutdown(listenfd,SHUT_RDWR);
    close(listenfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Client code

```
void * client (void)
{
    socklen_t           lenkeepalive;
    int                 sockfd, keepalive, n;
    struct net_pack recvline;       //pack for msg 
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;

    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {printf("client: socket error %d ( %s )\n ",errno, strerror(errno));}

    keepalive = 1;
    lenkeepalive = sizeof(keepalive);
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &keepalive, lenkeepalive) < 0)
    {
        perror("client: setsockopt()");
        shutdown(sockfd,SHUT_RDWR);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port   = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, servip, &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        printf("client: inet_pton error for %s\r\n", servip);


    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("client: connect to %s error %d ( %s )\r\n",servip, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        // send a msg

        encode(&recvline,"hello",H); //make a msg

        n = send(sockfd, &recvline, (strlen(recvline.msg)+4), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        if(n < 0)
        {printf("client: i cannot send, error %d (%s)\n",errno, strerror(errno));}

        bzero(&recvline, sizeof(recvline));

        //recv data from server
        while( (n = recv(sockfd, &recvline, MAXLINE, 0)) >= 0)
            {
                printf("client: recvline.msg - %s\n",recvline.msg);
                bzero(&recvline, sizeof(recvline));
            }
    }

    // some error occurs
    perror("client: recv()");
    shutdown(sockfd,SHUT_RDWR);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

In your case you should use sockaddr_un instead of sockaddr_in, and some necessary flags like `AF_UNIX`, `SOCK_DGRAM` and other.

Comment: Doesn't seen your last remark, sorry. Okay, I was confused some time ago about the unix-sockets because I thought these are like a named pipes. Now I see, that it some strange mix of socket and pipes... But anyway, the question is open -- I just doesn't understand, why the unix-socket remains open after the old server exits. It looks like I can create a new server, and use an old socket file.

Comment: Socket remains after the old server exits because you don't close it. But it doesnt work any more because socket is connected whith adress of old server's 'accept()' routin.

Comment: No, all the hypothesises wrong. At first I tried to explicitky `close()` it. At second, even if I doesn't, the socket should be closed when the application exits. And third: binding the old file popup the error `Address already in use`. I know it because I can't even launch the same application again without explicitly removing an old file.

Comment: 'Address already in use' error because socket is connected whith adress of old server's 'accept()' routin. Use `shutdown()` and `close()` like me. Socket SHOULD NOT be closed automaticaly when the application exits. You should do it manualy.

Comment: Anyway, right now I am (I just continue to work with it meanwhile) call the close() explicitly, but the file doesn't want to gone automatically. [n.m. also told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504203/why-an-unix-socket-file-remains-after-an-app-exits-can-i-create-new-server-with/24506801?noredirect=1#comment37941854_24506801) that I must remove this file.

Answer (score 0):

To act as a connection-oriented server, an application creates a socket, then *binds* it, then *listens* for incoming connections.

Then, for each incoming connection, the application *accepts* it and serves it.

There is a function for each of these actions: `socket`, `bind`, `listen` and `accept`.

All steps are necessary here, and all must be performed in the same application. You cannot create an bind a socket, and then let some other program use it.

A connection-oriented client needs to create a socket and then call `connect`.

Datagram-oriented communications do not have connections and do not use `listen`, `accept` and `connect`.

Comment: I was confused because I was sure that the unix-socket is something like a named-pipes. Anyway, why the unix-socket file remains after the old server exits. It looks like I can create a new server, and use an old socket file

Comment: You are confusing the socket objects as a part of the the sockets API (local to the program) and the filesystem objects called "unix domain sockets". You `bind()` the former to the latter. They are like file descriptors and actual files.

Comment: the both functions needed to create an unix-socket. `bind()` accepts a socket descriptor( `socket()`), and only after the bind the file appears. But if I exit from the application that created the file, file remains, even if I explicitly `close()` socket descriptor. So, can I bind a new server to this file? Or for what reasons it remains?

Comment: No, you cannot bind another program to it. You will get "address already in use" error. Normally you `unlink()` the file after use. I don't know why exactly they are not deleted automatically after closing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't research into the actual justification, but what I can assume is that the socket API itself doesn't care about the file.

You can compare this to connecting over IP. You bind to a port and then you disconnect from it, but the port always exists and never gets deleted.

For UNIX sockets, it makes sense to create the file if it doesn't exist (although I don't think the socket API itself creates the file, but rather requests its use, upon which the file is created automatically - perhaps by the OS), but, from the APIs point of view, it has no job to delete the file, just to not use it anymore.

Comment: Parallels you do make sense, but if we go into this analogy, then note that these "always existing TCP ports" take no space on the system until someone actually takes one. And after users of a TCP port disappear and the port is available again *(on `close()` or after a timeout)*, it again takes no structures or other space on the system, it "just exists", in a kinda mathematical sense. This is a contradiction with the UNIX-sockets case, where the file left behind does take space and causes problems by its existence.

Comment: Well, there are multiple problems. How can the server delete the file if the client is still using it? Also, an empty file takes virtually no space so unless you are working with a floppy disk it is of no concern. It is very likely that it doesn't even take any space at all if optimisations are applied. There are a lot of virtual files in UNIX that actually don't exist, like mostly all in /dev.

Comment: I see no problem. A file can be deleted disregarding if someone is using it, it's not even specific to unix-sockets. But a server sure should call `close()` beforehand, to disconnect clients explicitly. And no, the empty file does take some space. At the very least you have to keep its name somewhere. It's not a kinda mathematical concept like a port number, where whole ports range "just exists", without taking any space, until they're used. Same for virtual files in /dev, they do take space in RAM, because you have to keep somewhere their names, minor/major numbers, etc.